# Hyperledger Fabric: How to print out the fabric ledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We are interested in printing out the records that were written to the ledger in chronological order. What is the best way to do this? We use the [queryBlock](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryBlock) method to get a block but it returns a monstrous structure. Example [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/siddjain/5675e484d7be9cc635666a4b91e94161/raw/633bc43e088d77d93e2f690198ca2d0f8b3a0a8c/gistfile1.txt). With lot of effort we have been able to dig into the actual transaction data like this:

```
> obj.data.data[0].payload.data.actions[0].payload.action.proposal_response_payload.extension.results.ns_rwset[1].rwset.writes
[ { key: 'a', is_delete: false, value: '100' },
  { key: 'b', is_delete: false, value: '200' } ]
```

However one can hardly be expected to write that monstrous code to extract the records. How can we print out the ledger contents like:

```
a, 100
b, 200
```

and so on...

Further expansion of what we are looking for. We are looking for a standalone executable that we can run from the command line. It would accept the ledger location as input (e.g., `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/mychain`) and print out following table:

Date | Time | Who | Key | Value

Who is the identity who made change to the key-value pair e.g. alice@orgA